# jQuery Serialize Form to JSON - Make Input Array

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I am using a fairly standard JSON.stringify function, that gets passed across to a jQuery function that serializes this object.

However I'd like to make an modification to allow an array of inputs to be posted. Much like how the current solution handles a collection of checkboxes.

E.g.

```
<fieldset name="clothes">
  <input type="number" name="coat" />
  <input type="number" name="jacket" />
  <input type="number" name="jeans" />
  <input type="number" name="(guid)" />
</fieldset>
```

These are all items of clothing so I'd like to form them into something like:

```
{ "Clothes": { "coat" : 2 , "jacket" : 10 , "jeans" : 1 } }
```

In the above, the function needs to support an additional level of grouping. My first thoughts on this are to add a name to the fieldset. This seems logical to me. However as per HTML spec's the fieldset element isn't part of the form submission, so there would be some that would say adding a NAME to this element for this purpose, violates the specification. However, as the specification supports adding a 'name' attribute, I think this is perfectly valid.

In the context of the entire form, I'm looking for something that supports:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="Name" />
  <input type="text" name="Email" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="clothes">
  <input type="number" name="coat" />
  <input type="number" name="jacket" />
  <input type="number" name="jeans" />
  <input type="number" name="(guid)" />
</fieldset>
```

Giving...

```
{ "Name" : "John" , Email : "x@y.com" , "Clothes": { "coat" : 2 , "jacket" : 10 , "jeans" : 1 } }
```

I've posted a simplified version of my current code on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DR3EA/1/

Answer (score 1):

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/DR3EA/2/, but it cannot get the label data into result because I use fieldset to do serialize.

```
$.fn.serializeField = function() {
    var result = {};

    this.each(function() {

        $(this).find("fieldset").each( function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var name = $this.attr("name");

            if (name) {
               result[name] = {};
               $.each($this.serializeArray(), function() {
                   result[name][this.name] = this.value;
               }); 
            }
            else {
               $.each($this.serializeArray(), function() {
                   result[this.name] = this.value;
               });
            }
         });

    });

    return result;
};
```

The `result` would be

```
{"Name":"bb","Email":"cc","clothes":{"coat":"-1","jacket":"-2","jeans":"-2"}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mifeng, your response has given me the kick up the backside to sit down and take the problem apart a bit more! The proposed solution, as you say has a limitation/flaw - in that the checkbox/radio arrays will not get processed, as we don't support nesting in the above. It will also fail on a nested fieldset. However it's progress, so I'll have a crack and refactoring this and we'll see where we get! Many thanks :) Lau

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and ended up going with the [serializeObject](https://github.com/JasonBenn/jQuery.fn.serializeObject) jQuery plugin.  Instead of using a fieldset, format your `name` attributes like so:

```
<input type="text" name="work.street" value="320 3rd St">
<input type="text" name="work.city" value="San Fran">
<input type="text" name="work.state" value="CA">
```

Given the above inputs, `$('input').serializeObject()` returns a nicely nested JS object:

```
{ work: { street: "320 3rd St", city: "San Fran", state: "CA" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-serializeFields](https://github.com/jonathansp/jquery-serializeFields) plugin might be helpful, but you'll need to specify some attributes (eg data-name) so as to work like a key of each fieldsets (or container element).

HTML:

```
<form>
<fieldset data-name="clothes">
  <input type="number" name="coat" value="1" />
  <input type="number" name="jacket" value="2"/>
  <input type="number" name="jeans" value="3"/>
  <input type="number" name="(guid)" value="4"/>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var result = $("form").serializeFields();

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(result));
```

result:

```
{"clothes":{"coat":"1","jacket":"2","jeans":"3","(guid)":"4"}}
```

I have tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/zfj4Lprb/